# Updating a property of another property in a class

Tags: c#, class, oop, object, properties

I have very much a beginner question: I am sure I am missing something incredibly fundamental here

I have this simplified version of the code (use of arrays, etc..  is only for purposes of illustration):

```
DataObject dataObj = new DataObject(new byte[7]{1,1,1,1,1,1,1));

dataObj.Meta.Prop0 = 8;
dataObj.Property1 = new byte[5]{8,8,8,8,8};

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new byte[7]{8,1,8,8,8,8,8}, dataObj.GetData()); //<--- Fails.  array[0] is still 1.
Assert.AreEqual(8, dataObj.Meta.Prop0); //<--- Fails.  Prop0 never updated (still 1)
Assert.AreEqual(new byte[5]{8,8,8,8,8}, dataObj.Property1); //<--- OK.
```

Why does `dataObj.Meta.Prop0` does not return correct value?  I am updating the `_data` in the `DataObject.Meta` setter, however, if i put a breakpoint inside `Metadata.GetData()` method (which is called from inside `DataObject.Meta` setter), it is never triggered..

Below are the details of `DataObject` class implementation (Updated with implementations of `GetSubrray()` and `UpdateData()` as requested):

```
    public class DataObject
    {
        private byte[] _data;

        public DataObject(byte[] objectData)
        {
            _data = objectData;
        }

        public byte[] GetData()
        {
            return _data;
        }

        public Metadata Meta
        {
            get
            {
                return new Metadata(GetSubarray(0, 2));
            }
            set
            {
                UpdateData(0, value.GetData());
            }
        }

        public byte[] Property1
        {
            get
            {
                return GetSubarray(2, 5);
            }
            set
            {
                UpdateData(2, value);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateData(int start, byte[] data)
        {
            Array.ConstrainedCopy(data, 0, _data, start, data.Length);
        }

        private byte[] GetSubarray(int start, int length)
        {
            byte[] arr = new byte[length];
            Array.ConstrainedCopy(_data, start, arr, 0, length);
            return arr;
        }
    }

    public class Metadata
    {
        private byte[] _metadata;

        public Metadata(byte[] metadata)
        {
            _metadata = metadata;
        }

        public byte[] GetData()
        {
            return _metadata;
        }

        public byte Prop0
        {
            get
            {
                return _metadata[0];
            }
            set
            {
                _metadata[0] = value;
            }
        }

        public byte Prop1
        {
            get
            {
                return _metadata[1];
            }
            set
            {
                _metadata[1] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the `Subarray` method come from? That's not a standard method I'm familiar with. My guess is that it's copying a slice of the array - and so changing that *copy* won't change the original data.

Comment: And same with `Update` method. Please show us both.

Comment: @Sach they dont exist..  i made them up for example's sake to to show that I am updating array (and I know that functionality works).  `Subarray(m,n)` does something like `byte[] arr = new byte[n]; Array.ConstrainedCopy(_data,  m, arr, 0, n); return arr;`  and `Update(m,n)` does the opposite.

Comment: Can you get a working example, in .NetFiddle thanks.

Comment: @Sach: if i put a breakpoint on `return _metadata;` line in `Metadata.GetData()` method, it is never triggered at all.

Comment: You'll have to post code that's reproducible. Otherwise it's too difficult to see what's going on.

Comment: The issue is your Subarray method-- it uses `new` to create its result, meaning that the array of bytes is a different chunk of memory. Updates to one won't be reflected int the other. If you post the code for Subarray I can provide an answer that allows it to return a reference instead of a copy.

Comment: @TheGeneral as requested:  link to .NetFiddle: .https://dotnetfiddle.net/UvJKxr

Comment: @JohnWu please see my comment above.  I put the code in https://dotnetfiddle.net/UvJKxr

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments and the other answer posted, the fundamental problem with your code is here:

```cs
public Metadata Meta
{
    get { return new Metadata(GetSubarray(0, 2)); }
    set { UpdateData(0, value.GetData()); }
}
```

The fact that you're creating a new `Metadata` object makes this statement not do what you think it's doing:

```
dataObj.Meta.Prop0 = 8;
```

The `Meta` property getter is creating a new `Meta` object, which is then used to set the `Prop0` property. But this `Meta` object has no connection to the `DataObject` object. The object's `Prop0` setter is called, and then that `Meta` object is immediately forgotten about. There is no reference to it, it will eventually be collected by the garbage collector, and it has no effect on the `DataObject` object.

Given your current `DataObject` implementation, one way to fix the code would be to retrieve the `Meta` object into a variable, set the `Prop0` property, and then set the `Meta` property again:

```cs
Meta meta = dataObj.Meta;

meta.Prop0 = 8;
dataObj.Meta = meta;
```

Now, frankly I think that this overall design is just plain broken. The idea of storing these values in an array, and then trying to map array elements to individual properties, it's just asking for trouble. It will lead to exactly the kind of bug you have here, and makes it very difficult to understand and use the objects. If you *do* really want to use an array to back the properties, then you really should at least make sure that you only ever allocate the array and objects once, so that to the caller, the properties act like normal properties instead of having this weird "you have to save the object, modify it, and then set the property value again" semantics. For example, something like this:

```cs
public class DataObject
{
    private struct ByteSpan : IList<byte>
    {
        private readonly byte[] _data;
        private readonly int _start;
        private readonly int _count;

        public ByteSpan(byte[] data, int start, int count)
        {
            _data = data;
            _start = start;
            _count = count;
        }

        public byte this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index < 0 || index >= _count) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                return _data[_start + index];
            }
            set
            {
                if (index < 0 || index >= _count) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
                _data[_start + index] = value;
            }
        }

        public int Count => _count;
        public bool IsReadOnly => false;
        public void Add(byte item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public void Clear() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public bool Contains(byte item) => this.Any(b => b == item);
        public void CopyTo(byte[] array, int arrayIndex) => Array.Copy(_data, _start, array, arrayIndex, _count);
        public IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator() => _data.Skip(_start).Take(_count).GetEnumerator();

        public int IndexOf(byte item)
        {
            int indexOf = ((IList<byte>)_data).IndexOf(item) - _start;

            if (indexOf < 0) return -1;
            if (indexOf >= _count) return -1;
            return indexOf;
        }

        public void Insert(int index, byte item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public bool Remove(byte item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public void RemoveAt(int index) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }

    private readonly byte[] _data;
    private readonly IList<byte> _property1;

    public DataObject(byte[] objectData)
    {
        _data = objectData;
        Meta = new Metadata(new ByteSpan(_data, 0, 2));
        _property1 = new ByteSpan(_data, 2, 5);
    }

    public byte[] GetData()
    {
        return _data;
    }

    public Metadata Meta { get; }

    public IList<byte> Property1
    {
        get => _property1;
        set => CopyIList(value, _property1);
    }

    private void CopyIList<T>(IList<T> source, IList<T> destination)
    {
        if (source.Count != destination.Count) throw new ArgumentException("source and destination must be the same length");

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            destination[i] = source[i];
        }
    }
}

public class Metadata
{
    private IList<byte> _metadata;

    public Metadata(IList<byte> metadata)
    {
        _metadata = metadata;
    }

    public IList<byte> GetData()
    {
        return _metadata;
    }

    public byte Prop0
    {
        get => _metadata[0];
        set => _metadata[0] = value;
    }

    public byte Prop1
    {
        get => _metadata[1];
        set => _metadata[1] = value;
    }
}
```

To do the above, it is necessary to modify the `DataObject` interface a little. Specifically, instead of returning arrays, it has to return `IList<T>` objects. This allows the same array to be used as the underlying storage for all of the array-like properties that are exposed.

*(Aside: the above uses a custom `ByteSpan` type that implements the `IList<T>` that represents the subset of the underlying data array. If you can use .NET Core, you'll find the equivalent `Span<T>` struct which can be used instead.)*

If you insist on returning array values instead of `IList<byte>`, then you will have to modify the above slightly so that the property setters *copy* the values from the provided array into the underlying data array. Likewise, the getters will have to copy the values out. Unfortunately, this will lead to something very similar to what you're already dealing with, which is that the array being returned by the property cannot directly modify the underlying data array. If the caller only retrieves the array value and modifies that without setting the property again to that same array, the underlying data array won't be modified, and you'll have the same exact problem.

Even with the above version, where the properties use `IList<byte>` instead of `byte[]`, the setter still needs to copy the given list to the property's own list, because the list being passed to the setter may or may not be the original one. If it's not, then assigning the property's list reference to that would disconnect the property from the underlying storage. Only by copying the values from one to the other instead, can the property's list remain the same, and continue to reference the original underlying data array.

But at least by using `IList<byte>` instead of `byte[]`, the caller isn't *required* to set the property value again after modifying the list. Modifying the list will in and of itself modify the underlying data array.

I strongly recommend against using a data array as the underlying storage, but if you do, I just as strongly recommend that you *do* use something like the `ByteSpan` or `Span<T>` types to wrap the underlying data array in an object that callers can manipulate while directly affecting the underlying storage.

Comment: Thank you. I did understand your explanation that `Meta` property `get` creates new object that is not related to `DataObject`.  In my mind I thought I was taking care of that in the `set { UpdateData(0, value.GetData()); }`, where I was supposed ot be getting data back from this unrelated Metadata object and saving it to the array in DataObject.  I think this is the gap im not completely getting here:  why isnt `set` gets invoked when that new object gets updated.

Comment: _"why isnt set gets invoked when that new object gets updated"_ -- the property setter is called only when the property itself is assigned. The _value_ that the property returns has nothing at all to do with that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties#the-set-accessor

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but design is wrong!
You have copy of byte[] main data. example when you say

```cs
return new Metadata(_data.Subarray(0,2));
```

You have same data But copy of main data.
it is copy. Not reference main object!

```cs
private byte[] GetSubarray(int start, int length)
        {
            byte[] arr = new byte[length];
            Array.ConstrainedCopy(_data, start, arr, 0, length);
            return arr;
        }
```

So when you update Prop0 Prop1 etc.. on the Meta byte[] You think main data will be updated. Sorry but no. It is copy of data bytes.. not reference.

If you want to update main object, You should move this properties inside of Main object. Not copy of something.

Move your Prop0 Prop1 etc.. inside of main object. update main _data directly. Not copy of object.

```cs
public class DataObject
    {
        private byte[] _data;

        public DataObject(byte[] objectData)
        {
            _data = objectData;
        }

        public byte[] GetData()
        {
            return _data;
        }

        public Metadata Meta {
            get {
                return new Metadata(GetSubarray(0, 2));
            }
            set {
                UpdateData(0, value.GetData());
            }
        }

        public byte[] Property1 {
            get {
                return GetSubarray(2, 5);
            }
            set {
                UpdateData(2, value);
            }
        }

        public byte Prop0 {
            get {
                return Meta.GetData()[0];
            }
            set {
                UpdateData(0, new byte[]{ value});
            }
        }

        public byte Prop1 {
            get {
                return Meta.GetData()[1];
            }
            set {
                UpdateData(1, new byte[] { value });
            }
        }

        private void UpdateData(int start, byte[] data)
        {
            Array.ConstrainedCopy(data, 0, _data, start, data.Length);
        }

        private byte[] GetSubarray(int start, int length)
        {
            byte[] arr = new byte[length];
            Array.ConstrainedCopy(_data, start, arr, 0, length);
            return arr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im sorry, i dont really follow:  you want to move properties of `Metadata` object into `DataObject`?  thats not how i imagine it would work:  `Metadata` is a sub object of the `DataObject`.  Regarding working on the copy of the data when I try accessing `Meta`:  while this maybe is true, i also (theoretically) write back any modifications made on that copy in the setter of `Meta` (`UpdateData(0, value.GetData());`)